# Applying Gradient to LSTM layers using GradientTape raises "No gradients provided for any variable" error

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, reinforcement-learning

I'm currently setting up a Deep Deterministic Policy Gradient agent to interact with a crypto trading environment. The code works when I'm using `Dense` layers for the function approximator, but when I switch to `LSTM` or `GRU`s this error pops up when I call the `learn` method of `Agent`:

```
No gradients provided for any variable: ['actor_network_4/lstm/kernel:0', 'actor_network_4/lstm/recurrent_kernel:0', 'actor_network_4/lstm/bias:0', 'actor_network_4/lstm_1/kernel:0', 'actor_network_4/lstm_1/recurrent_kernel:0', 'actor_network_4/lstm_1/bias:0', 'actor_network_4/dense_8/kernel:0', 'actor_network_4/dense_8/bias:0'].
```

I'm using `GradientTape` to record the gradients and `optimizer.apply_gradients` to update the actor and critic networks. Please find the code snippets below:

```
#RNN version
class CriticNetwork(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, n_actions,name='critic', chkpt_dir='ddpg'):
        super(CriticNetwork, self).__init__()
        self.n_actions = n_actions

        self.model_name = name
        self.checkpoint_dir = chkpt_dir
        self.checkpoint_file = os.path.join(self.checkpoint_dir, self.model_name+'_ddpg.h5')

        self.lstm1 = LSTM(128,return_sequences=True,unroll=False)
        self.lstm2 = LSTM(128)
        self.q = Dense(1, activation=None)

    def call(self, state, action):
        action_value = tf.concat([state, action], axis=1)
        action_value = np.reshape(action_value,(32,1,44))
        action_value = self.lstm1(action_value)
        action_value = self.lstm2(action_value)
        q = self.q(action_value)

        return q

class ActorNetwork(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self,n_actions=1, name='actor',chkpt_dir='ddpg'):
        super(ActorNetwork, self).__init__()
        self.n_actions = n_actions

        self.model_name = name
        self.checkpoint_dir = chkpt_dir
        self.checkpoint_file = os.path.join(self.checkpoint_dir, 
                    self.model_name+'_ddpg.h5')

        self.lstm1 = LSTM(128,return_sequences=True,unroll=False)
        self.lstm2 = LSTM(128)
        self.mu = Dense(self.n_actions, activation='tanh')

    def call(self, state):
        state = np.reshape(state,(32,1,43))
        prob = self.lstm1(state)
        prob = self.lstm2(prob)
        mu = self.mu(prob)

        return mu

class Agent:
    def __init__(self, alpha=0.001, beta=0.002, input_dims=[33], env=None,
            gamma=0.99, n_actions=1, max_size=3000000, tau=0.005, 
            fc1=128, fc2=128, fc3=64, batch_size=32):
        self.gamma = gamma
        self.tau = tau
        self.memory = ReplayBuffer(max_size, input_dims, n_actions)
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.n_actions = n_actions
        self.max_action = 1
        self.min_action = -1
        
        self.actor = ActorNetwork(n_actions=n_actions, name='actor')
        self.critic = CriticNetwork(n_actions=n_actions, name='critic')
        self.target_actor = ActorNetwork(n_actions=n_actions, name='target_actor')
        self.target_critic = CriticNetwork(n_actions=n_actions, name='target_critic')

        self.actor.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=alpha))
        self.critic.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=beta))
        self.target_actor.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=alpha))
        self.target_critic.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=beta))

        self.update_network_parameters(tau=1)

    def update_network_parameters(self, tau=None):
        if tau is None:
            tau = self.tau

        weights = []
        targets = self.target_actor.weights
        for i, weight in enumerate(self.actor.weights):
            weights.append(weight * tau + targets[i]*(1-tau))
        self.target_actor.set_weights(weights)

        weights = []
        targets = self.target_critic.weights
        for i, weight in enumerate(self.critic.weights):
            weights.append(weight * tau + targets[i]*(1-tau))
        self.target_critic.set_weights(weights)

    def remember(self, state, action, reward, new_state, done):
        self.memory.store_transition(state, action, reward, new_state, done)

    def save_models(self):
        print('... saving models ...')
        self.actor.save_weights(self.actor.checkpoint_file)
        self.target_actor.save_weights(self.target_actor.checkpoint_file)
        self.critic.save_weights(self.critic.checkpoint_file)
        self.target_critic.save_weights(self.target_critic.checkpoint_file)

    def load_models(self):
        print('... loading models ...')
        self.actor.load_weights(self.actor.checkpoint_file)
        self.target_actor.load_weights(self.target_actor.checkpoint_file)
        self.critic.load_weights(self.critic.checkpoint_file)
        self.target_critic.load_weights(self.target_critic.checkpoint_file)

    def choose_action(self, observation, evaluate=False):
        state = tf.convert_to_tensor([observation], dtype=tf.float32)
        actions = self.actor(state)
        if not evaluate:
            actions += tf.random.normal(shape=[self.n_actions],
                    mean=0.0, stddev=0.05)
            
        actions = tf.clip_by_value(actions, self.min_action, self.max_action)

        return actions

    def learn(self):
        if self.memory.mem_cntr < self.batch_size:
            return

        state, action, reward, new_state, done = \
                self.memory.sample_buffer(self.batch_size)

        states = tf.convert_to_tensor(state, dtype=tf.float32)
        states_ = tf.convert_to_tensor(new_state, dtype=tf.float32)
        rewards = tf.convert_to_tensor(reward, dtype=tf.float32)
        actions = tf.convert_to_tensor(action, dtype=tf.float32)

        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            target_actions = self.target_actor(states_)
            critic_value_ = tf.squeeze(self.target_critic(
                                states_, target_actions), 1)
            critic_value = tf.squeeze(self.critic(states, actions), 1)
            target = reward + self.gamma*critic_value_*(1-done)
            critic_loss = keras.losses.MSE(target, critic_value)

        critic_network_gradient = tape.gradient(critic_loss, self.critic.trainable_variables)
        self.critic.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(critic_network_gradient, self.critic.trainable_variables))

        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            new_policy_actions = self.actor(states)
            actor_loss = -self.critic(states, new_policy_actions)
            actor_loss = tf.math.reduce_mean(actor_loss)

        actor_network_gradient = tape.gradient(actor_loss, self.actor.trainable_variables)
        self.actor.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(actor_network_gradient, self.actor.trainable_variables))

        self.update_network_parameters()
```

Any advice or help in terms of how to record and apply the gradient for LSTMs would help.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the problem is that you are using Numpy operations to define the computation logic (hence, the gradients cannot flow from that point onward); however, this should be done entirely using TF Ops or Keras layers. Specifically, in `call` method of `CriticNetwork` as well as `ActorNetwork`, instead of using `np.reshape` you should either use [`tf.expand_dims`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/expand_dims) (if you only want to add a new axis of size one to the tensor), or [`tf.reshape`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reshape), or [`tf.keras.layers.Reshape`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Reshape) layer (for more involved reshaping). For example, using `tf.expand_dims`:

```py
class CriticNetwork(keras.Model):
    #...
    def call(self, state, action):
        action_value = tf.concat([state, action], axis=1)
        action_value = tf.expand_dims(action_value, axis=1)
```

or using `tf.reshape`:

```py
class CriticNetwork(keras.Model):
    #...
    def call(self, state, action):
        action_value = tf.concat([state, action], axis=1)
        action_value = tf.reshape(action_value, (-1, 1, 44))  # Use `-1` for the first axis so that any batch size would be supported
```

or using `Reshape` layer:

```
class CriticNetwork(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, n_actions,name='critic', chkpt_dir='ddpg'):
        # ...
        self.reshape = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((1, 44))

    def call(self, state, action):
        action_value = tf.concat([state, action], axis=1)
        action_value = self.reshape(action_value)
```

And you need to do the same thing for the `ActorNetwork`.

---

**Side note:** I am not sure if this is just a demo code or not, but note that using RNN layers on a sequence of length one (i.e. having only one timestep) may not prove to be very beneficial.